# Corollary of Gauss' lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

**Gauss' Lemma:** If the primitive polynomial $f(x)$ can be factored as the product of two polynomials having rational coefficients, it can be factored  as the product of two polynomials having integer coefficients.

**Corollary:** If an integer monic polynomial factors as the product  of two *non-constant polynomials* having rational coefficients then it factors as the product of two integer monic polynomials.

I have proved the Gauss' lemma using the fact that product of two primitive polynomials is also primitive.

I guess that corollary follows easily from the Gauss' lemma since integer monic polynomial is primitive and then comparing the leading coefficients leads to $ab=1$ which is equivalent to $a=b=1$ or $a=b=-1$. In both cases we get the product of two integer monic polynomial.

Let me ask you the following question: Why the condition of corollary contains *non-constant polynomials*? What if one of them is constant?

**EDIT:** I have checked that if $f(x)$ is an integer monic polynomial and it factors as the product of two polynomials from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ where one of them is constant then statement of corollary is also true.

Comment: My guess is that the statement of the corollary, in the case where one of the factors is a constant, is just uninteresting. This case can be done by hand without using Gauss' Lemma at all.
(If $P$ is your polynomial, it is just saying $P=r\times (\frac{1}{r}P)$.

Comment: In your Corollary you should also state that the two integer monic polynomials are again *non-constant*. Otherwise the Corollary becomes meaningless. (Since for every monic $f\in \mathbb Z[X]$ we have a decomposition $f = 1\cdot f$ into monic integer polynomials.)